# O "mau uso" da medalha de ouro pode ocasionar algum tipo de sanção?

Tags: debate, medalhas, razões-fechamento

Sabemos que quem possui a medalha de ouro de uma *tag* possui o poder de fechar perguntas como duplicada. Existe algum tipo de sanção sobre o usuário por utilizar o poder de fechamento de forma equivocada?

Comment: Caro Sam, só pra constar o downvote na sua pergunta aqui no não é meu, acho que o debate te lá o seu mérito, apesar de achar um pouco desnecessário traze-lo para o Meta, mas a comunidade somos comunitários e o mais democráticos que a SO nos permite ser, então espero que isso tudo esclareça o que deve ser esclarecido e que a sua pergunta sirva para outros possiveis mal entendidos. Desejo-lhe uma boa noite.

Comment: Se foi avaliado errado, a comunidade pode votar pra reabrir.

Comment: @sam uma coisa que eu demorei para entender aqui em relação as duplicatas (no inicio eu até reclamava muito), é que o que faz a pergunta duplicata são respostas que resolvem o problema de ambas, porque a reposta que vale, claro que nada impede o AP de editar a pergunta e pedir alguma coisa a mais que não tenha na outra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Nota:** não entrarei no mérito de discutir se o fechamento citado foi correto ou não, até porque isso não faz parte da discussão - mas prezo pela resposta do Guilherme como direito de resposta a afirmação dada na pergunta.

Ao meu ver, a discussão é válida e deve existir aqui.

O problema talvez seja que sempre será prematuro discuti-la.

O detentor da medalha de ouro tem o poder de fechar uma pergunta sem depender de outras pessoas e não precisamos discutir isso - e nem foi questionado isso. A questão é: e se a pessoa utilizar o poder de forma equivocada?

Bom, você coloca no final da pergunta:

> Na minha opinião acho isso extremamente prejudicial. Quando se tem "poderes", não se pode usá-los de forma negligente.

Começarei discutindo primeiramente a segunda frase: *Quando se tem "poderes", não se pode usá-los de forma negligente*. Falar *não se pode* é pesado e injusto. Ninguém é perfeito. Ao ver o correto a se dizer é *não se deve*. Com grandes poderes, vem grandes responsabilidades e devemos sempre buscar aplicar estas responsabilidades da melhor forma. Erros acontecem e sempre vão acontecer.

E é por isso que eu digo que a discussão é prematura. Se julgar que alguém fechou a pergunta de forma equivocada, basta votar para reabrir. Como sabe, ela entrará na fila de análise e será votada. Se mais pessoas concordarem, a pergunta será reaberta. Isso acontece direto.

Quanto a outra afirmação, *na minha opinião acho isso extremamente prejudicial*, nós entramos no outro mérito da discussão. Errar uma vez não prejudica a comunidade. Se a pergunta foi fechada de forma equivocada, poderá ser reaberta e a comunidade segue. O que prejudica é errar constantemente e se você perceber que os erros de um usuário são recorrentes, basta sinalizar para a moderação.

Agora, a pergunta que fica para a moderação, que é, de fato, a sua pergunta, é: ao sinalizar um usuário por mau uso de seus poderes, o que poderá acontecer? Sabemos que é caso a caso, mas quais são as ações tomadas pela moderação nesses casos? Acredito que, em primeira instância, apenas orientam, mas e em outras instâncias? Há o poder por parte da moderação remover uma medalha do usuário?

Comment: Sim, a moderação pode remover o privilégio do usuario, caso ele abuse ou use de forma indevida, só não sei afirmar de fato se isso é restrito aos CMs ou moderadores elegiveis tambem pode fazer.

Comment: @Articuno acho que nem CMs podem tirar privilégio algum, a não ser banindo que tira todos. O que dá para fazer, e não é pela simples vontade do moderador, é suspender da fila de análise. Até suspensão de perguntar ou responder só o sistema faz, e aí talvez um CM possa também. Não há provisão para tirar a medalha ou seu poder, o que seria legal ter, na verdade seria legal uma bela reformulação geral.

Answer (score 10):

> Até o momento editaram a pergunta e agora resposta perde um pouco o sentido, pois minha intenção não foi só defender meu posicionamento, mas orientar ao AP sobre como funciona Regex e DOM, a pergunta original ao qual essa resposta tem foco é esta:
>
> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7239/2

Belo título sensacionalista e claramente mostra que não entende bem o caso, **o voto de fechamento foi meu**, foi justo e tenho conhecimento o suficiente para fazer um bom julgamento e justo, aliás eu entendi muito bem a pergunta, o fechamento alí foi pensando em apontar a melhor saída para o AP com uma excelente resposta do colega Zuul:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44734/3635

ok vamos por partes, primeiro você afirmou algo que não é a realidade:

> Muito bem, sabemos que o usuário detentor da medalha tem essa prerrogativa, porém se notarem na pergunta que foi motivo de fechamento, nota-se claramente que se trata de outro assunto completamente alheio à pergunta fechada:
>
> [Capturar div pela class](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44730/8063)
>
> Não é nem pelos títulos diferentes, mas porque ambas tratam de assuntos completamente diferentes. A única coisa em comum é que ambas citam `curl`.

Não, a prerrogativa não **tem nada haver com curl**, mostra que é um entendimento bem errado de sua parte, isso é apenas especulação sua, em nenhum local afirmei nada sobre curl, é uma afirmação totalmente errada, a questão é **Regex vs DOM**, e é nisto que você vai ter que se prender para entender aonde você se confundiu.

HTML, XML e afins são linguagens "livre de contexto", ou melhor dizendo, regex não entende a semântica de um HTML *de maneira fácil*, pois HTML é uma linguagem de marcação, outra coisa é importante dizer antes de partir sobre a explicação técnica, existe muita confusão sobre o entendimento no site sobre **suporte técnico** e sobre **soluções reais** e funcionais dentro da tecnologias citadas, que inclusive este parece um dos caso que levou ao engano todo de sua percepção.

Querer resolver tudo na base da regex é não entender o conceito das tecnologias citadas na pergunta em debate aqui.

Não vou negar absolutamente que você não pode usar regex, **você pode sim usar regex**, afinal de contas "funciona", mas é o seguinte, existem tecnologias que atendem (API `DomDocument`, `XPath` e afins em PHP), então porque reinventar a roda?

Então te pergunto, você quer dizer que a pergunta é sobre regex especificamente, então a solução tem que ser um regex?

A resposta para isso é **NÃO**

**Então tenha atenção a isto:**

Deste tipo de pensamento que se é com `preg_match` deve ser respondido estritamente com `preg_match`, **podem sair respostas** com códigos absurdamente **problemáticos** dos quais as pessoas que fizeram as respostas **acham que são infalíveis**, mas na real são códigos que podem fazer com o minimo de mudança no HTML, ou podem funcionar parcialmente, que é pior do que falhar, por exemplo, hoje o div é assim:

```
<div class="titlebar-title titlebar-title-lg">filme</div>
```

Ai amanhã muda para isto:

```
<div class="titlebar-title titlebar-title-lg">
    <span>Foo</span>
</div>
```

Pronto, o tal regex já vai extrair:

```
<span>Foo</span>
```

Quando o esperado era apenas:

```
Foo
```

Ou seja retorna mais coisas do que o esperado, ou então o autor do código muda a ordem das classes, o que não afeta o html, mas vai afetar o [regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) e pronto, tudo se quebra, regex é para coisas que você tem controle, para um HTML que não tem controle dar uma resposta com regex é o mesmo que dar uma arma com defeito para alguém que não sabe atirar, não vai servir de nada e a pessoa ainda poderá se machucar.

A questão aqui não é os poderes que eu tenho com a tag de ouro em PHP e nem muito menos o meu suposto mal uso, o problema aqui é que você esta agindo de forma errada e poderia simplesmente fazer de forma simples, chegar e perguntar algo como:

> Caro Guilherme por que não usar regex para HTML?

Ai eu responderia tranquilamente via chat ou qualquer outro meio de comunicação do qual poderíamos debater sem termos que ficar fazendo "textões" e eu diria:

> Então meu caro Sam, html pode mudar, etc etc etc.

Antes de mais nada ao notar algo que supostamente você discorda você deve pensar que existe um bom motivo e conversar com as pessoas para aprender mais sobre o que você não entende, e não sair fazendo uma acusação como se as pessoas tivessem cometido equívocos gravíssimos.

Se a pergunta debatida aqui ficasse aberta teríamos respostas com soluções em regex e que seriam respostas falhas e com certeza eu ou outro usuário do site que entende de `DOM` e PHP daria uma contra-resposta explicando tudo que te expliquei aqui sobre os problemas de usar regex para resolver situações com DOM e a solução que eu apontaria seria com `XPath`, assim como eu já fiz outras vezes:

- [RegExp não pega o valor do input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59525/3635)
- [Pega name via regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304592/3635)

---

### Temos alguma pergunta sobre HTML e Regex?

Temos sim, um dedicada somente a isto:

- [Por que Regex não deve ser utilizado para tratar HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/3635)

Comment: Não foi isso que perguntei. A questão do fechamento não é o assunto da pergunta, e sim sobre a medalha de ouro.

Comment: Caro @sam estou respondendo ao seu entendimento que é equivocando, como você falou exatamente nesta parte *"Não é nem pelos títulos diferentes, mas porque ambas tratam de assuntos completamente diferentes. A única coisa em comum é que ambas citam curl."*, você fez afirmações totalmente erradas, a prerrogativa não era o curl, aqui a resposta explica bem o porque disto. Sobre o uso da medalha de ouro é o que eu já disse, converse com quem fechou, tá tudo respondido dentro do que foi perguntando, agora se restou alguma duvida por favor comente. Obrigado.

Comment: Blz então. Se eh isso, eh isso. Grato!

Comment: @sam um link que pode abrir a sua mente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/3635 - Espero que ajude!

Comment: Soh pra constar, sua resposta possui um erro de interpretaçao. A prerrogativa que mencionei foi em relaçao a medalha, e nao ao curl. Inté!

Comment: @sam sendo prerrogativa sobre a medalha ou não o entendimento é que você fez uma *afirmação*, ou seja estou falando da minha real prerrogativa (direito especial que possuo sob a medalha) foi sobre não ser baseada em curl. Então acho que agora dá pra você entender melhor o que eu disse.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento , o termo certo seria chamar HTML de linguagem livre de contexto; linguagens "irregulares" pega um conjunto mais amplo de linguagens disponíveis.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado, atualizando!

Comment: Meu jovem, nao estou questionando se uma coisa eh melhor ou mais adequada que a outra, e ateh concordo com vc nesse ponto. Meu questionamento eh o fechamento da pergunta. Se vale fechar uma pergunta nessas circunstancias e nesse criterio, otimo, eu nao sabia que podia. Agora que estou sabendo, vou começar a fechar tb tudo quanto eh pergunta de javascript usando esse mesmo criterio.

Comment: @sam independente se entendeu ou não agora, eu respondi exatamente ao como você formulou a pergunta, você afirmou e evidenciou bem claramente que eu errei, quando na verdade não errei em nada, eu contei o que aconteceria se a pergunta continuasse aberta, procure na resposta acima a parte que eu falo isto: *"se a pergunta ficasse aberta sairia umas respostas com regex"*, tá explicado o que ocorreria, seriam respostas os quais levariam a uma resposta minha ou de outra pessoa do PORQUE NÃO USAR REGEX, com links apontando para o que já foi linkado como dup. 

Comment: Não resisti a deixar aqui este link mítico sobre html e regex no SOen: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)